# How to create a dictionary that contains every values from a set?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I'm having trouble trying to create a dictionary that uses a set as key values, and value that contains partial element of key will be added to the key value.

For example, If I have a set below:

```
{( 'a', 'b', 'c' ), ( 'a', 'd', 'b' ), ( 'z',), ( 'z', 'j' ), ( 'z', 'w' ), ( 'z', 'w', 's' ), ( 'z', 'm' )}
```

How can I make a dictionary looking like:

```
{( 'a', 'b' ,'c' ): {( 'a', 'b', 'c' )}, ( 'a' ,'d' ,'b' ): {( 'a' ,'d' ,'b' )}, ( 'z' ): {('z'),('z','j'),('z','w'),('z','w','s'),('z','m')}, ( 'z', 'j' ): {('z', 'j')}, ('z', 'w'): {('z','w'), ('z', 'w', 's')}}
```

Order does not matter, it have to include every elements. Such as since value `('z', 'w', 's')` contain `('z')` and `('z','w')`, it also added to for those keys as well.

Comment: Could you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: It is kinda impossible since sets are unordered.

Comment: This site is not a coding service.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 this is a valid question. the question doesn't ask for code explicitly.

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan - No it isn't, and yes it does. If you don't think it's asking for code, what do you think it's asking for? It reads like a homework dump.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the problem can be solved using different approaches like Suffix Tries. the answers can provide the approaches and let the person posting the question decide for himself.

Comment: @U9-Forward incorrect. the ordering has to be only within the element of the set and since the elements are tuples the ordering will be maintained

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan I realized that you can simply sort them by length.

Comment: @U9-Forward yes. but may not be the most efficient if it is a large collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly not the most efficient:

```
myset = {( 'a', 'b', 'c' ), ( 'a', 'd', 'b' ), ( 'z',), ( 'z', 'j' ), ( 'z', 'w' ), ( 'z', 'w', 's' ), ( 'z', 'm' )}
dict_of_set = {k: set(x for x in myset if set(k).issubset(x)) for k in myset}
```